# Snap photos with Logitech webcam in C# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webcam, logitech

I am working on a Kiosk project where I want the camera to snap photos of the person using the kiosk after they go through certain screens. The camera I am using is a Logitech C310 USB webcam. I have looked online for solutions but nothing I have found so far is giving me the results I need. I basically just want it to automatically take the picture without needing any kind of acknowledgement from the user. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Websites do not have access to the client's hardware. You cannot make HTML or JavaScript access a webcam and take a picture.

Comment: Hello, 

so there is no way to make my asp.net application take pictures without having the user acknowledge it? It would be on a kiosk, so not really something people are gonna access from their homes. What would you suggest I do instead if this doesn't work? The goal is to take pictures of them when they enter their personal information for the County's records. Like an extra security camera.

Comment: Id say a rich client.

Comment: Via WebRTC websites do have access to client side media such as cameras. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/